# Visual Studio 2012 Database Diagram?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have done very little in C# and am following the Head First C# book. There's a part in the book where it asks me to create a Database Diagram for my SQL database, but in the Database Explorer there is no Database Diagram node/folder.

I have heard that Microsoft dropped the Database Diagram feature, but is there another way to create a Database Diagram that would be easy enough for me to understand?

Comment: unless the database is complex, you don't really need a database diagram. Just create the tables and relationships...

Comment: How would i do this? I'm a total newbie to C# and SQL integration with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give SQL Server Management Studio a try. It has a table diagram tool. Here's the express edition (SQL Server 2008 Express): http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593

You can find it for 2012 SP1 here, as well: http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579

Comment: It still is a PITA to install SSMS 2008 though; I think 2012 has it standalone?

Comment: Better take the 2012 SP1 Management Studio: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579

Comment: Thank you. I have one question, how do I start a server to connect to so I can import my .mdf from Visual Studio? When I boot SSMS, it asks for a server to connect to, and then I mount the mdf, right? How do I make a server that comes up there?

Comment: I have LocalDB but I don't know my server name.

Comment: Do you have SQL Server installed locally? Use its name.

Comment: You would typically have named it when you installed the server. You can also look in SQL Server configuration manager.

Comment: OK, I got it. One problem, I connect and attach my ddatabase, but it says it's read only. I'm using the same user that is the owner of the database but I can't edit it.

Comment: I also can't access my C:/Users/__ folder, the attach browser won't display anything in it.

Comment: Try setting windows permissions on your database folder/files to be readable by mysql

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry I'm so clueless.

Comment: At this point I'd recommend educating yourself on some of these things through books/tutorials. You'll probably get better and more info than here. StackOverflow is meant more as a programming Q&A than a classroom.

Comment: Answer is no longer valid. someone with very little grasp on reality has removed the  Database Diagram tool from SSMS.

Answer (score 15):

I like the way Entity Framework 5 will allow you to import database objects and then it will diagram the tables, indexes, relationships, etc.   Or you can do it the other way, create the diagrams and then publish it to a database.  This works so well I suspect it is why the Database Diagram was dropped in SQL Server.   EF5 is probably in your Visual Studio environment right now.

[image: EF5]

To create an EF5 diagram, right click a directory (usually the directory is named "Model"), and select "Add" / "New Item" and then select "ADO.NET Entity Data Model".   Name it, and then select "Generate from database".  The rest is selecting or generating a connection string and then selecting the database objects.

Best part is that this is the start of what I would recommend when you get to the point in your learning where you need a data access layer, I can not recommend EF5 high enough.

Comment: Where is this Model directory?

Comment: You can just create it in your project. It comes with the project template when I create a Silverlight project.

Comment: Hmm. Where is this directory in my project? I'm using a Windows Form Applicaion.

Comment: Just add it yourself, I was saying by convention it is normally named "Model".  Right click the project, select Add / New Folder.

Answer (score 8):

I just solved a similar problem - 
my VS2012 server explorer was not showing Database diagrams

The problem was that the database I was using was the SQLEXPRESS installed by VS2012 (and was sql 2012 based)

I am using SSMS 2008R

When I moved the offending database to a SQL 2008R2 server - my database diagrams appeared

This took many hours to resolve and I hope this note helps somebody else save this frustration