# Show visual diagram of tables and relations in Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

Is there an option to show a visual diagram of database tables and there relations? I have looked almost everywhere in the Solutions Explorer, but can't find anything!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2012 Database Diagram?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131304/visual-studio-2012-database-diagram)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the following link. That may help you

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms171976(v=vs.110).aspx

"The Database Diagram Designer is a visual tool that allows you to design and visualize a database to which you are connected. When designing a database, you can use Database Designer to create, edit, or delete tables, columns, keys, indexes, relationships, and constraints. To visualize a database, you can create one or more diagrams illustrating some or all of the tables, columns, keys, and relationships in it."

Note Important

You can use the Database Diagram Designer to update databases in SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008, and SQL Server 2008 R2. However, SQL Server 2012 doesn't support this feature.

Comment: Also there is possibility as it is same as Visual Studio 2012 as fuchs777 has mentioned.

refer:  1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131304/visual-studio-2012-database-diagram 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547925/missing-diagram-folder-in-database-explorer-at-visual-studio-2012